# Is it possible to AND 2 NOT IN's for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is it possible to AND 2 NOT IN's instead of doing a nested one?

```
SELECT..FROM..WHERE..X NOT IN (...) AND Y NOT IN (...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine any valid conditions.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible.  Depending on what you're trying to do, though, you may not get the results you expect.  For example, if X and Y are two columns which together produce a concatenated key, then this won't work to accurately identify the records.  You'd instead want to list out groups, like so:

```
SELECT..FROM..
WHERE.. not ((X = 'foo' AND Y = 'bar') OR (X = 'blah' and Y = 'blah2') OR ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should just work fine. I see no problem with it.